# Python code behaving differently on Ubuntu and MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing a flask application and do most of my development on my MacBook using pycharm.

Recently I deployed the application to the remote server and ran some tests. The remote server has Ubuntu 16.04 running with python 3.6 ( running the same version of python on my MacBook as well).

Now every time I tested a certain function on the remote server, the server ran out of disk space. This was caused by a certain function that I had implemented to zip some files.

Here is the code,

```
local_dir = 'some_path/'
new_zip_file = os.path.join(local_dir, "{}.zip".format('some_name'))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip_file, 'w') as new_zip:
         for file in files:
             new_zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
```

On MacBook, the above code block works as intended. It goes into the specified folder, finds the files and then zips them into a new file. the zip file is created inside the same folder where the content of the zip file are found.

On Ubuntu, it goes into a recursion causing the zip file to explode.

Now I know how to fix the issue on ubuntu, but my question is, why is the change in behaviour on two different OS?

Comment: What line recurses? `for file in files:`? Does it also do that if you create a [mcve], containing only the minimal `os.walk`?

Comment: This is broken, anyway - if `local_dir` contains any subdirectories, the .zip of their contents will overwrite the .zip in the directory itself.  As for the recursion problem, this is probably caused by some_name.zip already existing, and therefore being included in the `files` list - check for this, and skip the `.write()` in that case.

Comment: I figured out where it went wrong. Although I did upgrade python in ubuntu to match my development environment, the virtual environment had been created before I upgraded python hence it had the older version of python3.5.2, while the development environment had python 3.6.6. According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html), there's been some changes to the zipfile module. I migrated the virtual env in Ubuntu to python3.6.6 and the code started behaving as expected. Needs to be written in big letters, VERSION MATTERS.